# How to use Meredith’s axiom for classical logic?

Tags: lo.logic, axioms, formal-proof

I’ve been self-studying axiomatic systems for classical logic for a while. The standard Hilbert/Mendelssohn/Lukasiewicz axiomatizations were a bit tough for me to get used to without using the Deduction Theorem, but now I’m confident with those systems.

I recently learned about Meredith’s axiom for classical logic:

$((((A \to B) \to (\neg C \to \neg D)) \to C) \to E) \to (E \to A) \to D \to A$.

Could anyone give me tips for constructing proofs in this system? It seems obvious that one just needs to find the correct substitution of an instance of the axiom into the antecedent of another instance of the axiom, but I can’t seem to get any further than that strategy. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Conceptually, there is no other strategy than what you described. You have to guess the right substitutions and applications of modus ponens (which is likely quite nontrivial) to derive a basic list of more useful formulas, such as axioms of one the more usual systems that you are already familiar with. Meredith’s system is designed to be minimalist, it’s very much *not* designed to be convenient to use.

Comment: Do you have any pointers on which instances to choose? Or is this system beyond pieces of paper and whiteboards?

Comment: Did you look at Meredith’s original paper where he introduced this axiom? It should be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/meredith.html and the links there for the proofs you want.

Comment: I would usually comment along the lines of 'perhaps reproducing some part of the work here would improve answer quality', but the nature of these results precludes this comment. Thank you for the reference, Gerry.